# Microsoft Word, define part of the page to appear at the beginning of each page

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm preparing an invoice template in Microsoft Word. Each page of invoice should contain the same header (date, address etc.) How can I define text in one place to appear at the beginning of every page? Is it possible to modify this "header" in one place to make it being modified in other places too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. It is called a header, just like you would think. You can usually edit it just by double clicking in the margin at the top of the page, where the header would go.

In Word 2010, you can also click "Header" on the "Insert" tab of the ribbon. Once you begin editing the header, you can also enter things like the page number, the current date or time, or other things (see the "quick parts") menu.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Word are you using?  In most recent versions (2007 and above for sure, maybe in 2003?) you can edit the header by double-clicking on the header/footer space on a page.  By default, this will edit the header/footers for all pages.

Once you're in the header/footer editing mode, you'll see a new tab on the ribbon called "Design".  This can let you do things like make the first page header different, make the headers for even/odd pages different from each other, insert page numbers and more.